# Windows Phone 8.1 UIElement size limitation

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

On Windows Phone Silverlight 8 the maximum UIElement size is 2048x2048.

Does this limitation still exist on WP 8.1 with Windows Runtime XAML?

Comment: Well, the easiest still is probably just to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

```
  <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Width="150"
                  Height="40000"
                  Background="Green" Margin="20"></Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

It's works!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no size limitations on Windows Runtime applications. In both Phone and Store application, you can the UIElement in any sizes (both width and height).